# Process with independent increments: relation of increments to process value at later time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X_t,t\geq 0$ be a process with independent increments, $X_{t+s}-X_t$ is independent of $X_r,r\leq t$.

Can something similar be said about a *later* value and and an *earlier* increment, for example $X(1)$ and $X_{t+s}-X_t$  for $t+s \leq 1$?

Comment: Replace `Markov process` by `process with independent increments` (and $r\leqslant s$ by $r\leqslant t$).

Comment: Thanks, I've made the edits. But doesn't "Markov process" imply "independent increments" and then "independent increments" implies "Markov property"?

Comment: Please edit "Markov property" as well. // Re the question in your comment, $X=\exp(B)$ (with $B$ standard Brownian motion) is a Markov process with dependent increments.

Comment: And now the title... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processes $(X(t))_{t\geqslant0}$ such that, for every $t\geqslant0$ and $s\geqslant0$ such that $t+s\leqslant1$, $X(1)$ is independent of $X(t+s)-X(t)$, are very rare since this condition includes the hypothesis that $X(1)$ is independent of $X(1)-X(0)$.

If $X(0)=0$ almost surely (or if $X(0)$ is almost surely constant), this implies that $X(1)$ is independent of itself, that is, that $X(1)$ is almost surely constant.